# Prefixing wrapped lines printed in bash prompt by command/application

Tags: linux, bash, prefix, word-wrap

I compile on a remote target and the long warnings and errors thrown by g++ commonly wrap in the terminal, making it rather hard to read when reading the output. Is there a way to prefix every line printed to the console with a colored character? I've already modified my PS1 to better see commands input, maybe there is something I can add to the PS1 definition?

Comment: What is your terminal ?

Comment: /bin/bash over a remote ssh connection

Comment: I mean konqueror, gnome-terminal, xterm ?

Comment: Oh, it's putty in windows

Answer (score 1):

1. Write the output to a file and then view it in something that lets you control line wrapping. Like `less -S`
2. Pipe the output through `sed -e 's/^/--> /` or whatever else you want added to the start of each line.
3. Find something that can colorize gcc output (I believe tools for this exist).